# amazon php access to private files

Tags: php, api, amazon-s3

I am uploading all files to Amazon s3 and set them to private. The only thing that I want to access the files is my php script. Is that possible?

I know you can add an id # and give that person read privileges to a bucket. How would I create a new user (the php) which can have the appropriate privileges?

So I think there is creating the appropriate user and giving them access and then writing a script to allow that user to access the file.

Is there a php script somewhere that gives an example of the php giving access? I looked at the docs and there is alot of information about uploading and deleting buckets and all that. I just want the ability to read the file.

Answer (score 1):

I use s3 by Donovan Schönknecht.  http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class .This will do what you need.